# How to record how much time user has spent on my node?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I want to record the time a user has spent on my particular node so I could show a pop up to the user to register once the user has read 3 article. But the user must have spent at least 30 seconds on each node.

There is the [Time Spent](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_spent) module available, but I wonder if I can merge it with another (custom) module I have created (which records the number of nodes user have visited)?

Comment: You'll want to write a custom module then. You could hack the functionality into a theme, but modules are how you extend Drupal's core functionality. Don't fight it, it's not worth the time. Failing that, just use plain old javascript

Answer (score 3):

## Without using any custom modules

Drupal core doesn't have any such feature. So if you don't want to consider using a contributed module, the only options you have is to:

- Write a custom module (or further enhance the custom module you already have for it).
- Add something like a javascript to the theme(s) you're using.
- Wait for a future release of Drupal (core) that may include such feature.
- Consider using a contributed module (e.g. as further explained below).

## Using the Javascript Timer module

The [Javascript Timer](https://www.drupal.org/project/jstimer) module (available for D6 and D7) seems to be a possible answer to your question. Here is a quote from its project page:

> ... provides a timer API that can hook HTML elements to javascript widget objects. This is useful if you want a moving timer/clock or a widget that updates every second. It comes with widgets for a count-down timer, a count-up timer, and a clock. It uses jQuery and a single event loop to handle as many timers as you need on a single page.

Its [Readme.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/jstimer/tree/README.txt?id=refs/heads;id2=7.x-1.x) file contains various examples, both [Inline HTML Examples](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/jstimer/tree/README.txt?id=refs/heads;id2=7.x-1.x#n23) and [PHP Input Format Examples](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/jstimer/tree/README.txt?id=refs/heads;id2=7.x-1.x#n68).

[Comment #4 in issue #1195560](https://www.drupal.org/node/1195560#comment-5430722) contains an interesting comment that may help to get you going:

> It allows for redirecting to a new URL or refreshing the existing page.
>   On the setting page it is called "Timer complete redirect". If you use a "redirect path" of `<reload>` it will just reload the current page.

Comment: Changed the question. Can I get any help now?

Comment: @RakeshVerma In future please make sure you ask the actual question you want an answer for _first time round_. It's not fair to make others spend their time preparing answers to questions you're just going to throw away the answer to. Just have a little thought for the people who are volunteering their time and effort to help you

Comment: Thank you @Clive for confirming what I was also thinking (but wasn't sure if it was appropriate to share ...). Some people ask 3 questions in a single question (like a few days ago), others seem to "reuse" existing questions, like this one. Oh well, unless I'm assumed to now "delete" this answer (or if it gets removed via moderation), I'll soon "reuse" it to adapt my answer accordingly (as soon as I can, and had some time to think about my best possible answer) ... Does this mean that "Editing your own question is OK, as long as you do not change your mind (too much)?"

Comment: The idea is not to change the original intent. It's less of a problem if there isn't an answer (although someone could easily be working on one, of course), but if it's answered then at best it just creates a confusing Q/A combination. Asking a new question is probably the right thing to do. It doesn't help your wasted efforts, unfortunately, but the question was quite vague to begin with so it might have been better to get more info via comments first. Fine lines, I know

Comment: My turn again: changed my answer (and think I found a way to somehow reuse part of my original answer to the original question) ... Curious if my help here will be sufficient ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that I am thinking you can handle in javascript with cookies. For example lets create a cookie called "show_pop_up";

1. Every time a user views a page for over 30 seconds check if he has cookie called show_pop_up.
2. If a user doesn't have the cookie, create the cookie and add the value of 1 (A better solution would be to store the user in the database and store the user identifier in the cookie but for simplicity just showing you this way)
3. If a user already has a cookie, check what number they have in the cookie.
4. If the value is equal to 4, show the pop up and increase the cookie value by 1.
5. If the value is less than 4, increase the cookie value by 1 (don't show the pop up).